# Why did Arrow play homage to Blue sky?

Tags: breaking-bad, reference, arrow, arrowverse

Why did Arrow play homage to Breaking Bad in S02E06 by showing Blue Sky?

[image]

The Walking Dead did that but those two were from the same network, but why did the Arrow TV series do that? Is there any reason for this reference?

Comment: You sure this even was a reference to Breaking Bad? Did the show say anything about what that blue stuff was supposed to be? Was that really crystal meth?

Comment: @TomCody what more a blue crystal drug can signifies ?

Comment: @TomCody Confirmed by Arrow's creator Marc Guggenheim: http://underscoopfire.com/blue-meth-on-arrow/

Comment: @AnkitSharma *"what more a blue crystal drug can signifies"* - Well, that's what I was asking, if it's supposed to be a drug at all. It could as well have been any other kind of blue stuff.

Comment: @TomCody its mentioned as drug for sure , i think felicity even said something like " this much of drugs".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an example of **Genre Fractal**.

TV shows, even though they may be completely unrelated, are able to communicate meaning by referencing each other and using those references as narrative shorthand.

If a drug is shown and it is needed to be conveyed that this is, for example, an incredibly pure iteration of that drug; they can dye the drug blue and hence reference another TV show, borrowing the lore built within that property as a way of bypassing heavy exposition.

The reference won't land for everyone, but for those who 'get it', its a nice way of condensing the significance of something and participating in a referential exchange of 'easter eggs'.

It's all the rage these days.

Comment: Seems like a valid point, +1